# Deploy a nodejs server for web CRM for production

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking for any method or tutorial to deploy on local server/computer a nodejs express app. this will be for production environment. All I read about solutions like zenit now, localtunnel, forever, pm2 and similars is that they aren't recomended for production environments. The idea is to have a public web without hosting. I eed that the method allows to maintain more than one node/web active at the same time.

Comment: By local server/computer, you mean that your machine will be acting as server or what?

Comment: Yes, that will be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people say a component is not recommended for production, it does not mean that it is not stable. Most of the times it means that it is not a full blow solution that considers all the aspects of a production deployment:

- scalability
- fail-over
- security
- configurability
- automation
- etc.

If you are trying to build a solution that has precise requirements (requests per seconds, media streaming, etc.) you should post in your question as well to make it concrete. If this is not the case, you just have to install a basic setup that runs your configuration and fix bottlenecks as they appear. Don't try to build a theoretically correct solution now.

A couple of examples:

**A classical setup** (goes well with Do-It-Yourself deployments)

- install Git + (Node.js and NPM) + (Forever or equivalent) + your database (e.g. MongoDB) + (NGINX or HAProxy) on your favourite/accepted Linux distribution
- clone each Node.js app in its own directory
- install cronjobs for basic monitoring and maintenance
- add scripts to dynamically remove/add NGINX web server configurations based on deleted/added Node.js apps

**A more modern setup** (goes well with AWS/GCE deployments but also possible locally with tools like [skaffold](https://skaffold.dev/))

- install a Kubernetes cluster on a couple of machines
- prepare a base Docker container image that matches all your Node.js applications
- if required, add a Dockerfile to each Node.js application to build one Docker image per application based on the base Docker container image
- add a [new deployment](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/introduction-to-yaml-creating-a-kubernetes-deployment/) for each of your Node.js application
- Kubernetes will do for you the "keep-alive"
- fill-in the plumbing between your server network (DNS, IP, ports) and the IP's provided to you by Kubernetes (NGINX or HAProxy would also fill in this hole)

Comment: I'´ll study both cases.  Very clear solution. Thank you veru much